# Cursor to Retrieve Dataset for taking AVG and STDEV

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, cursor

I have objects being made from a template. There are several datapoints on these objects, and I measure each datapoint on every part to see how far off of the template the parts are. I want to take the most recent 100 measurements and find their average and standard deviation. Here are specifics on my table values:

- reqt_id: Each different reqt_id represents a datapoint on the object
- var: Each var is one measurement.
- inst_id: Every new measurement (var) gets an inst_id, so this is used to find out which measurements are the most recent

So in summary, if my parts have 5 different datapoints that Im measuring, I will have 5 different reqt_ids. If I have 500 parts that Im measuring, there will be 500 var measurements per reqt_id. What I want to do with my SQL stored procedure is write a cursor that will grab the most recent 100 var measurements from a certain reqt_id, then take its AVG and STDEV, then move to the next one. Ideally, my table will look like this:

**..REQT_ID..|..AVG..|..STDDEV..**

..0001.........|..0.32..|..0.0012.....

..0002.........|..0.27..|..0.0005.....

Below is what I have so far for my cursor. It doesn't work so far, so I was wondering what exactly it is I'm missing.

```
 DECLARE cursor_reqt_ids CURSOR FOR
 SELECT r.reqt_id, AVG(r.[var]), STDEV(r.[var])
 FROM RESULTS r

DECLARE @reqt_id AS INT

OPEN cursor_reqt_ids
 FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_reqt_ids INTO @reqt_id
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
       SELECT TOP 100 r.[var]
       FROM RESULTS r
       WHERE r.[var] != 0
       ORDER BY r.inst_id DESC
 END
 CLOSE cursor_reqt_ids
DEALLOCATE cursor_reqt_ids
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
       SELECT TOP 100 r.[var]
       FROM RESULTS r
       WHERE r.[var] != 0 AND r.reqt_id = 4898
       ORDER BY r.inst_id DESC
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_reqt_ids INTO @reqt_id --include this line so you can retrive next records and casuse the loop to terminate
 END
```

Your loop going to infinite loop because you didnt fetch data inside your while loop so you @@FETCH_STATUS  never become 1 to terminate the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, a totally different approach without cursor, should work from sqlserver 2005+:

```
;WITH a as
(
SELECT distinct reqt_id 
FROM RESULT
)
SELECT a.reqt_id, AVG(b.[var]) AVG, STDEV(b.[var]) var
FROM a
cross apply
(
SELECT top 100 r.[var] 
FROM RESULTS r
WHERE r.[var] != 0
AND a.reqt_id = r.reqt_id
ORDER BY r.inst_id DESC
) b
GROUP BY a.reqt_id
```